# GAE/J Async Datastore API: how to do the equivalent of a UNIX select?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

The Java Google App Engine Async Datastore API provides a way to do an async read and then ask later if it is done yet and if you want, block on it with an optional timeout.  However the one thing that I want to do that I can't find a way to do is the equivalent of a UNIX select.

That is, I want to:

1. issue a bunch of, say, reads to the datastore and then
2. just go to sleep until ANY one of them comes back.

As far as I can tell, the API as it is requires me to just loop through the Futures returned by the async reads and ask isDone() until one of them says true; this burns CPU time that I'm paying for to no use.

Am I missing something or is there no way to get the effect of a UNIX select using the GAE/J Async Datastore API?

Answer (score 0):

dan and i discussed this offline. the short answer is, there's currently no direct way to do this, but java and python in app engine both support threading, so you could easily do it in userland. more to the point, go's channel and select language primitives do exactly this, so it's definitely worth a look.